# "Declared Prefix" error? XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, monogame

I am a little bit confused by this error, provided it doesn't give me any information on what is wrong nor can I find any information about it. here is a screen shot of the error:

[image]

This has happened after I wrapped a SwapChainBackgroundPanel in a Page as it was causing issues with the Windows 8 tablet simulator.

Any ideas what might be going on here? I am a little lost. Any help is GREATLY appreciated! (this is a MonoGame XAML project)

Answer (score 0):

I found out why this is an issue; it is quite simple. If you have assembly information in your SwapChainBackgroundPanel move it into the "Page" tag. This will solve the issue. Remember to remove the references out of the SwapChainBackgroundPanel as well. In other words:

```
  <Page 
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
```

which were previously in the the SwapChainBackgroundPanel